# Filemaker Pro 12: Inserting New Record with ExecuteSQL Script

Tags: sql, filemaker

I'm trying to figure out how select info from Table A and then inserting that information into Table B with the ExecuteSQL script. I see how it works by hand, but I cannot seem to make that step where I can use the result of a search to then enter a new record into another table.

Comment: Wich RDMB's are you using, MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle...? What have you tried so far? Post some samples, some code. Right now will be hard to answer your question, read the faqs to know how to ask a correct question and get some answers.

Answer (score 2):

I have found success using SQL insert and FileMaker using a third-party plugin from Dracoventions called SQL Runner. You can find it here: http://www.dracoventions.com/products/2empowerFM/family/sql.php

If you need a code snippet then I can provide that as well.
jared

Answer (score 0):

Execute SQL is not meant to be used this way. You use Execute SQL to work with ODBC data sources to insert, delete, or update data; to select data and import into FileMaker you use the Import step with the same ODBC source.

FileMaker 12 has a new SQL *function* that can be used for FileMaker own tables, but it can only be used to select data, not to modify them. There are also plug-ins that let you use SQL with FileMaker tables.

In FileMaker you normally don't use SQL, but write a script. FileMaker scripts are pretty much like macros and work the same way the user would work. In your case the script would go to a layout, select the records (perform find), go to another layout, and import records from the table associated with the first layout.